# Rotation of 3D Vector by π/2 around axis Vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given  Vectors a and b. Choosing an axis that is normal to both a and b given, which can be obtained by their cross product , k = aXb . Now Rotating the Vector b by π/2 around k. 
We have the formula for Rotation as

$$ v_{rot} = v Cosθ + (k.v) (1-Cosθ) k + Sinθ k \times v $$
So Now rotating Vector b around k which is (aXb) by (π/2)

$$ b_{rot} = b Cos(π/2) +(k.b)(1-Cos(π/2)) k +Sin(π/2) k \times b $$
Since $ Cos(π/2)= 0 $ and $ Sin(π/2) = 1 $  , 
   $$ b_{rot} =(k.b) k + k \times b $$
   $$ =((a \times b) . b) k + (a \times b) \times b $$

Applying scalar triple product rule above  that $(a \times b).b = 0 $

$$ = 0 - b \times (a \times b) = b \times (b \times a) $$

Does this not all end up being Zero?

Comment: I suppose $k$ should be a unit vector, so you'd better define it as $a\times b/(|a|\ |b|)$. And no, the result is not zero.

Comment: I forgot to mention it , but I assumed k a unit Vector.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. $b\times a$ is orthogonal to both $a$ and $b$. If neither is zero and they are not parallel, you get a nonzero vector that is orthogonal to $b$, so $b\times(b\times a)$ must also be nonzero. Moreover, it lies in the plane spanned by $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Just learned that CrossProduct is not associative. I had presumed bx(bxa) = (bxb)xa. Thanks for response.